# flyway-spring4-test 3.1 brings conflicting dependency on slf4j 1.5

Tags: maven, slf4j, flyway

I have dependency on SLF4J 1.7. It known to have conflicts with previous versions which is brought in classpath by [flyway](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions/flyway-spring4-test/3.1). How to manage this?

```
[INFO] +- org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring4-test:jar:3.1:compil
e
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`<dependencyManagement>`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) for `org.slf4j` artifacts with a property `${slf4j.version}` so you can manage the versions of all SLF4J artifacts from a central place in your POM.

This will override any version defined by Flyway.

(Of course, you'll have to figure out for yourself which version of SLF4J is compatible with both your application *and* Flyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flyway-core dependency instead of flyway-maven-plugin.